# Can't make work an ajax post to php

Tags: php, jquery

Where it's my problem for me the code look's fine

```
$.post("../Backend/buscarCliente.php",{tipoBusqueda:"'"+$('#sltTipoBusqueda').val()+"'"},respuesta);
```

the php

```
<?php  
    //include all DAO files
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    require_once('include_dao.php');
    echo $_POST['tipoBusqueda'];
 ?>
```

i'm already debugged with charles debugging proxy and send this message, so i think the path it's good

[image]

Comment: Is PHP error reporting enabled? It looks like you're getting an empty response which could be due to an unhandled and unreported error

Comment: Is this live? Can you provide a URL? (Está en línea? Puedes proveernos a un URL?)

Comment: Start out really simple, first just do an echo `$_POST['tipoBusqueda']` without the includes and see if that works.

Comment: no i can't provide a public url, i tried putting the route the php route in the browser but doesn't throws and error

Comment: thanks @Interstellar_Coder it was the include. putting like an answer to setting like aprrove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start out really simple, first just do an echo `$_POST['tipoBusqueda']` without the includes and see if that works.